# How to control the valid return of mock object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch, python-decorators

```py
def create(user):
    user.password = hash_function(user.password)
    db.add(user)


@patch('hash_function')
def test_create_user(hash_function):
    create(User())
    hash_function.assert_called()
```

When I only need to assert_called with `hash_function`. I don't care about the return value, just want to know this function has called.

So I use `hash_function.assert_called()` in the last of test function.

But the code is break because: `db.add(user)` don't allow to push the user with the password is a `mock object`.

The reason "password is a `mock object`" is hash_function already a mock object.

So I wonder, is this safe to write test code with @patch, because it make your object become a mock, then when another function use the return value of mock(). It's gonna break the code.

Comment: Give your mock a `return_value` (as argument or attribute) that won't raise an exception.